# Save as CSV by macro - quiet mode - VBA 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I writing a macro to save the data in Excel sheet as CSV format - VBA 2010

I just have 2 issues at the end of the macro after everything is done.

1) In the command `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` I used the option `ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges` to guarantee overwriting the file if exist in the same folder with the same name, this option should overwrite the existing file in quiet mode without asking the user if he wants to overwrite the existing file or not.

It was working in the below syntax

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\File1.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
  xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
```

And if a file with the same name was exist it was overwriting 
But this option is not working although it was working for example when saving the file in normal Excel format but it is not working when saving as CSV.

But it is not working in the below syntax

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\File1.csv", FileFormat:= _
  xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
```

What I mean by 'It is not working' is that it is not overwriting the existing file and still displaying the message that there is a file with the same name exists and is asking the user if he wants to overwrite it or not.

As this is a macro so I don't want any interference from the user.

2) When I use the command `ActiveWorkbook.Close` to close the file after converting it to CSV, I have the message 'Do you want to save the changes (Yes/No).

I also want to save the file in quiet mode without having this message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part, add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` right before you do the SaveAs and add `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` right afterward.  That suppresses the overwrite message and automatically saves over the old file.

Answer (score 1):

For the item 2, Try this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

It will close without the question.

Jair Batista

Comment: Sorry but can you please advise the difference between using the operator "False" and "True" after the command "ActiveWorkbook.Close"? Is there any reference to explain such VBA options?

Comment: What I mean is not controlling the 'Save As' message ... I mean controlling the 'Yes' or 'No' as VB Action in the 'Save As' message by default to 'Yes' or 'No'

Comment: The "False" argument ignores the message "Do you want to save the changes (Yes/No)". Automatically select "No".